# For (w < y.length) stucks the browser tab JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, for-loop

I tried to make a code that returns many "9" characters to a string according to an int value.

Ej.: If "y" is equal to 5, "w" should return "99999".

I used the "for" instruction, but it makes the tab freeze.

The code:

```
var w = "";
var y = "";
function Calc()
{
    x = document.getElementById("inputX").value;
    y = document.getElementById("inputY").value;
    for (var i; i = y.length; i++)
    {
        w += 9;
    }
}
```

Thanks! (and sorry for my bad english).

Comment: If you want `i < y.length`, don't write `i = y.length`. Of course that never will be falsy and end the loop

Comment: it's interesting that you have a `<`  in the title, but don't use it in the code

Comment: You're right. I completely missed that. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code. I have changed the condition in the for loop and and initialized `i` variable.

```js
    
    function Calc()
    {
        var w = "";
        var y = "";
        x = document.getElementById("inputX").value;
        y = document.getElementById("inputY").value;
        for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
        {
            w += 9;
        }
        console.log(w);
    }
```

```html
X : <input type="text" id="inputX"><br>
Y : <input type="text" id="inputY"><br>
<button type="button" onclick="Calc()">Calculate</button>
```